# Trying to shrink a partition for installing ubuntu alongside windows but it gives an error:"New Size Can't be bigger than the device size."

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, gparted

I've been trying to install ubuntu alongside windows on my computer but unallocated space which I made in disk manager in windows doesn't show up on gparted while installnig ubuntu. So I tried shrinking my main hard drive partition but I get this error.

[image: Error]

This is what my partitions look like right now.
[image: Gparted Overview]

`sda4` is the one I'm trying to partition.

Comment: the error could be because the shrinking of the device has already taken place in Windows but Ubuntu is depending on the partition table which probably has not been updated. if possible, boot into the live version of Ubuntu and use the '[fdisk](https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Partition/fdisk_partitioning.html)' tool to update the partition table of the device. additionally, you could use '[fdisk](https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Partition/fdisk_partitioning.html)' to partition the shrunk volume to FAT so that the Ubuntu installer can detect it

Comment: Have you tried to split it in gparted? https://www.wikihow.com/Split-a-Partition-Using-GParted